# jQuery UI Datepicker going out of scale

Tags: jquery, html, css

My Datepicker is changing shape and stretching across to the very end of the screen. What could be wrong? Here is my code:

Also, how can I alter the date in the jQuery so it appears as dd-mm-yyyy?

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
        <title>Beauty Factory Bookings</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js">    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="heading1">
        <p>Select Your Treatment</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <select><?php echo $options; ?></select>
    <div class="heading2">
        <p>Select Your Date</p>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <div class="heading3">
        <p>Select Your Time</p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    .heading1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .heading2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 3%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .heading3 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 3%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .dropdown select {
        margin-top: 1%;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 320px;
        background: #ff656c;
        border: 1px solid #e15960;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    img {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-left: 12px;
    }

    .headertext {
        float: right;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-right: 3%;
    }

    body {
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/4mKmYMb.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center;
        background-size: cover;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: a JSFiddle would be great

Comment: working fine here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrQvYx

Comment: in JSFiddle works fine too. It might be the browser or something like that.
And to change de dateformat you have to do it with this: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: None of  your div tags are closed

Comment: have you tried without the google fonts?

Comment: No, let me try without google fonts.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. I closed all the div tags and didn't fix the problem either. ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to close your html divs

```
<div class="heading1">
    <p>Select Your Treatment</p>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <select><?php echo $options; ?></select>
</div>
<div class="heading2">
    <p>Select Your Date</p>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</div>
<div class="heading3">
    <p>Select Your Time</p>
</div>
```

And to change the date format, add a dateFormat option to your datepicker function

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```